# Angular 2 Routerlink in for loop

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

trying create Menu with below code

```html
<aside id="left-panel">
 <span class="minifyme"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i>
 </span>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li *ngFor="#menu of menus" [class.open]="menu === selectedMenu"
    (click)="onSelect(menu)"><a [routerLink]="[menu.action]"> <i
     class={{menu.icon}}></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">{{menu.displayname}}</span>
     <b *ngIf="menu.childrens.length>0"> <em class="fa"
      [ngClass]="{'fa-minus-square-o': menu === selectedMenu, 'fa-plus-square-o': menu !== selectedMenu}"></em>
    </b>
   </a>

    <ul *ngIf="menu.childrens" [class.show]="menu === selectedMenu">
     <li *ngFor="#submenu of menu.childrens" (click)="onSelect(menu)">
      <a> {{submenu.displayname}} </a>
     </li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</aside>
```

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {RouteConfig,RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {MenuService} from './menu.service';
import {Menu} from './menu';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-menu',
  templateUrl: 'app/menu/menu.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,RouterLink,RouteConfig]
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public menus: Menu[];
    public selectedMenu: Menu;
   
    constructor(private _menuService: MenuService) { }
    getMenus() {
        this._menuService.getMenus().then(menus => this.menus = menus);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getMenus();
    }
     onSelect(menu: Menu) { this.selectedMenu = menu; }
}

Getting following error, please suggest
```

EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on DecoratorFactoryBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 Error: No Directive annotation found on DecoratorFactory
    at new BaseException (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:7351:21)
    at DirectiveResolver.resolve (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:6654:13)
    at RuntimeMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:22303:47)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:22371:22
    at Array.map (native)
    at Array.map (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js:10:16820)
    at RuntimeMetadataResolver.getViewDirectivesMetadata (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:22370:25)
    at TemplateCompiler._compileNestedComponentRuntime (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:24329:63)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js:24314:26
    at Array.forEach (native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use RouteConfig within the directives attribute of your component since it's not a directive but a decorator.

You can notice that the RouterLink directive is contained into ROUTER_DIRECTIVES.

Using this should be enough:

```
directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
```

Moreover your need to configure routes on your component with the @RouteConfig decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-menu',
  templateUrl: 'app/menu/menu.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,RouterLink,RouteConfig]
})
@RouteConfig({
  (...)
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  (...)
}
```

Have a look at this link to see how to configure this:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Tried that, but getting below   Error: Component "MenuComponent" has no route config.

Comment: Yes because you didn't define routes on your component with RouteConfig decorator. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i have defined RouteConfig in app.component.ts, do i need to add in current page as well? getting this error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Child routes are not allowed for "/MaterialFlow". Use "..." on the parent's route path.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, i figured out error, i have not created all routelink in routeconfig

Comment: Pleased to hear that. I didn't see why you can't use the route configuration of a parent component...